# text on top of video using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```css
.video {
 z-index: 0;
 position: relative;
}

.videoText {
 z-index: 1;
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
  
  <div class="videoContainer">
  
   <div class="video embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video src="" autoplay muted loop></video>
   </div>
   
   <div class="videoText">
    <article>
     <p>Nullam a condimentum mauris.</p>
    </article>
   </div>
      
  </div>
    
 </body>
```

Is there a way to put content (etc. text, div...) on top of an embed video using Boostrap. I can do that without Boostrap.

Comment: You do not need to stick with Bootstrap. Bootstrap is a CSS library to start from. Add your own CSS and play around a little. Try https://codepen.io/icutpeople/pen/whueK

Comment: @Max Pringle thank you for your suggestion. I can do that without bootstrap, but I'm trying to take advantage of bootstrap for later. Adding text on top of a video is just 1 of the things I need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 steps:

Start by placing the image and the text in something that will contain them both. Then modify the CSS

```css
.VideoAndText {position: relative;} 
.VideoAndText .col {position: absolute; z-index: 1; top: 0; left: 0;}
```

```html
    <div class="VideoAndText">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe width="250" height="250" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KBALcN701NU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p>Hello World</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a jsFiddle illustrating: http://jsfiddle.net/sX982/779/

Comment: thank you. actually, you don't need to use iframe tag. the things I needed were the top: and left:.